# Visibility rules for mixin inheritance with variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, variadic-templates, template-mixins

Consider I inherit from a variadic template the entire arguments list. How are the arguments inherited?

```
// snippet
template<typename... R>
class foo
    : public R... {
public: 
};
// ....
using foo_inst = foo<bar_1, bar_2>;
```

I tried it, and it seems **all** `R`'s are inherited public (not just the first one). **Is this defined behavior?**

I tried it with gcc and msvc (thanks to [jaggedSpire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388928/visibility-rules-for-mixin-inheritance-with-variadic-template#comment50755049_31388928) also with clang), all with same results. The compilers not even mentioned any warnings. You can see a running example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/053fcb6bdda23235).

Comment: I consider this expected. However, I'm not sure what the standard says on it, if anything.

Comment: It works with [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/053fcb6bdda23235), too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the defined behaviour. Quoting from `14.5.3[temp.variadic]\4`

> A
>   *pack expansion*
>   consists of a
>   *pattern*
>   and an ellipsis, the instantiation of which produces zero or more
>   instantiations of the pattern in a list (described below). The form of the pattern depends on the context in
>   which the expansion occurs. Pack expansions can occur in the following contexts:

The relevant context from that list is:

> —  In a *base-specifier-list* (Clause  10 ); the pattern is a
>   *base-specifier*.

Thus, in the parameter pack expansion `class foo : public R...`, the pattern is the *base-specifier* `public R`, making the pack composed of types `T1, T2, ... , Tn` expand to `public T1, public T2, ... , public Tn`. (Ellipsis in the previous sentence are used in the mathematical sequence-specifying sense.)